# Dynamics AX 2012 Business Connector Errors

Tags: microsoft-dynamics-gp

I am seeing continuous Business Connector errors in the event log.  Third-party applications that use the Business Connector will completely crash whenever they try to access anything in AX.

If I stop all services, except for Microsoft Dynamics, the flow of errors in the event log does not slow down, so I believe the problem is in AX itself.

Here are the two most common errors:

```
 6.0: Unable to connect to an Application Object Server. A company name or server name     
 may not be specified correctly in the client configuration, or the server specified may    
 not be available. The specified resource type cannot be found in the image file

 6.0: Unable to connect to an Application Object Server. A company name or server name   
 may not be specified correctly in the client configuration, or the server specified may 
 not be available. The specified resource type cannot be found in the image file
```

There are literally hundreds of these in the course of just a few minutes.

Enterprise Portal is installed, and appears to be working.

I've also completely re-installed the AOS, Business Connector, and Client; and also upgraded to CU7.  No change so far.

Any suggestions?

Thanks